# how to replace mutilple foerign id with one primary id

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

i have a table called BUID(ID,Name) - ID is primary key
 and Table Details(DetailsID,NomineeID,NominatorID,NominationID) - DetailsID is primary key and other ID are value from BUID.

Now i need to generate report table from Details table by replacing NomineeID,NominatorID,NominationID with appropriate values from BUID table.

How to do it.
Please help.
Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question but I think this is what you are looking for.  Basically you will reference `BUID` multiple times with different alias' each time joining back to `DETAIL` with a different column.

```
CREATE TABLE BUID (ID int, Name varchar(100))
CREATE TABLE Details (DetailsID int, NomineeID int, NominiatorID int, NominationID int)
GO

SELECT Nominee.Name AS Nominee,
    Nominiator.Name AS Nominiator,
    Nomination.Name AS Nomination
FROM Details
JOIN BUID Nominee
    ON Details.NomineeID = Nominee.ID
JOIN BUID Nominiator
    ON Details.NominiatorID = Nominiator.ID
JOIN BUID Nomination
    ON Details.NominationID = Nomination.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You join to the buid table more than once using a different alias each time.  Something like this:

```
select whatever
from details join buid nominee on nomineeId = nominee.id
join buid nominator on nominatorId = nominator.id
same for nomination
etc
```